# Querying a result returned by mongoose in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am relatively new to Node.js, Mongoose and MongoDB.

I want to perform filter functionality and want to filter products by criteria selected by the user.

Is it possible in Node.js to query a response returned by Mongoose?

Sample response from Mongoose as below:

```
[ { _id: 589860c21f9997fce3502f10,
    title: 'Watch',
    brand: 'PUMA2',
    store: 'ZARA',
    for: 'MALE',
    size: '32',
    colour: 'RED',
    userId: '58a420cd7c77aca4b3ce34cd' },
  { _id: 5899bd33c28dbdf2b938f698,
    title: 'Watch 2',
    brand: 'PUMA',
    store: 'ZARA',
    for: 'MALE',
    size: '32',
    colour: 'RED',
    userId: '58a420cd7c77aca4b3ce34cd' },
  { _id: 5899bd59c28dbdf2b938f69a,
    title: 'Watch 4',
    brand: 'PUMA',
    store: 'ZARA',
    for: 'MALE',
    size: '32',
    colour: 'RED',
    userId: '5899bde3c28dbdf2b938f69e' }]
```

Now how can I query this response to select data based on brand.

Comment: Have you tried JavaScript's native [**`filter()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method like `var puma = response.filter(function(data){ return data.brand === 'PUMA'; })`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help everyone, finally got nice plugin called array-query which helped me to achieve what I want.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/array-query

Answer (score 0):

For finding PUMA brand, then query will be

```
db.collection.find({'brand': 'PUMA'})
```

Comment: Your solution is to get data from collection in db, but I want to get result from response which I got from previous query. So how to store above sample response somewhere and then how to query it to get data by brands?